# Django 1.11 is not loading css files

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

I have the next configuration:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^manager/', include('manager.urls')),

    #Static pages
    url(r'^index', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
    url(r'^', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
    url(r'^contact', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact.html'), name='contact'),
    url(r'^services', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='services.html'), name='services'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'pf.app.pfs',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets"),
    #'/var/www/static/',
]
```

I executed the command:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

And the files are generated, also I added a css file with a single rule but and executed the command again.

But, in the momento to add it to my html file

```
    <head>
        {% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" />
</head>
```

in the html I get:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css">
```

And in the terminal:

> "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1766

What I have wrong in my static files configuration?

[image]

Comment: This is the same for ``DEBUG = False`` and ``True``?

Comment: This is just an issue in local development or prod?

Comment: @Grimmy yes, its the same is I haver the `Debug` as `true` or `false`

Comment: Isn't ``BASE_DIR`` the root of your repo? Not ``./oversite``?

Comment: `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`